# How to set siteSpeedSampleRate value in google analytics using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have used this link https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics to add a google analytics to my Angularjs 1.5 project but I didn't find a way to set siteSpeedSampleRate.I have added `AnalyticsProvider` dependency injection and tried this to set the value like this `AnalyticsProvider.setAccount({ tracker: UA-XXXX-12, siteSpeedSampleRate: 100 });` but didn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you injecting the provider into your controller and app module?

Comment: Yes.I did everything which is mentioned in the link and the Google analytics are showing as well but I don't know how to set siteSpeedSampleRate value. rest all is working fine.need help on setting siteSpeedSampleRate value.

Comment: Removing ```siteSpeedSampleRate```, the error disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax to do it is:

```
AnalyticsProvider.setAccount({
    tracker: 'UA-XXXX-12',
    fields: {
      siteSpeedSampleRate: 100
    }
});
```